# How to bind multiple arrays in one over an loop

Tags: javascript

I want to put all the information of Nr22_array_0 and Nr22_array_1 in one array over an loop function with an trick. I think in php it would works, but i didn't try it atm. Have just the meaning, that i did that one time. In that javascript case it doesn't work, because it looks that all i write is wrong, because they see it as an non object, see Version 1 - 3 Output's in the code. I dont know how to hande it to get an output like that: ["apple","food","car","test","food","car", "miau"]. forgot to say thats just an example for 2, but i need it for N time Nr22_array_N. thx

```
let Nr22_array_0 = ["apple","food","car"];
let Nr22_array_1 = ["test","food","car", "miau"];
let Nr22_array_new = new Array();
let Nr22_array_names = new Array();
let Nr22_i = 0;
let Nr22_to_run = 2;

function Nr22_pushArray( var_to_safe, x ){
    var_to_safe.push.apply( var_to_safe, x );
}

while ( Nr22_i < Nr22_to_run ){
    Nr22_array_names.push( "Nr22_array_" + Nr22_i );
    Nr22_i++;
    //console.log( "Nr22_array_names: ", Nr22_array_names );
    //OUTPUT = OK: ["Nr22_array_0", "Nr22_array_1"]
}

Nr22_i = 0;
while ( Nr22_i <  Nr22_to_run ){
    // Version 1:
    //Nr22_pushArray( Nr22_array_new, Nr22_array_names[Nr22_i] );                   
    //console.log( "Nr22_array_new: ", Nr22_array_new[Nr22_i] );
    // OUTPUT - NOK: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object 
    // Version 2:
    //Nr22_pushArray( Nr22_array_new, "Nr22_array_" + [Nr22_i] );                   
    //console.log( "Nr22_array_new: ", Nr22_array_new );
    // OUTPUT - NOK: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object                   
    //document.write(Nr22_array_names[Nr22_i]);
    // Version 3:
    //Nr22_pushArray( Nr22_array_new, Nr22_array_0 );
    //console.log( "Nr22_array_new: ", Nr22_array_new );
    // OUTPUT - NOK: sure 2x the same ["apple", "food", "car", "apple", "food", "car"]                  
    Nr22_i++;
}
```

Comment: `Nr22_array_new = Nr22_array_0.concat(Nrr22_array_1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So dudes. first i wanna excuse myswelf because i forgot to say its for N arrays. 2nd big thx @kemicofa to give me such a huge answer and good tips to figure out how i could handle that. and also to you all, who tried to help an bad coder. (i know, i know. the english skills could be also a little bit better =/ ) i am not proud about that code, because the code is a little bit confusing to read and i think an good coder could write an shorter version, but it works. =D

```js
    let Nr22_array_0 = ["apple","food","car","tec"];
    let Nr22_array_1 = ["test","food","car","tec", "miau"];
    let Nr22_array_2 = ["bred","milk","suger", "water", "medicine"];    
    let Nr22_array_new = new Array();
    let Nr22_array_names = new Array();
    let Nr22_array_names_2 = new Array();
    let Nr22_i = 0;
    let Nr22_to_run = 3;

    // create an Array with an list of all arraynames
    while ( Nr22_i < Nr22_to_run ){
     Nr22_array_names.push( "Nr22_array_" + Nr22_i );
     Nr22_i++;
    };

    // complex function atm who has to make also the reduce and
    // filter function for the strings, but it doesnt work for an 
    // maped array (should be written new!)
    function mergeNArrays() {
     return Object.values(arguments).reduce((acc, cur) => {
      acc.push(...cur.filter(item => !acc.includes(item)))
      return acc;
      console.log("acc: ", acc);
     }, []);
    }

    // create an maped object array 
    const res = mergeNArrays(
     Nr22_array_names.map(eval)
    );
    
    // recursive function to read the object array and push the single values 
    // in an single string array 
    Nr22_i = 0;
    Nr22_i_2 = 0;    
    while ( Nr22_i < res.length ){
     Nr22_i_2 = 0;
     while ( Nr22_i_2 < res[Nr22_i].length ){
      Nr22_array_names_2.push( res[Nr22_i][Nr22_i_2] );
      Nr22_i_2++;
     }
     Nr22_i++;
    };
    
    // reduce function for duplicate words  
    var NR22_uniq = Nr22_array_names_2.reduce(function( a, b ){
    if (a.indexOf(b) < 0 ) a.push(b);
     return a;
    },[]);
    NR22_uniq.sort();
    document.write(NR22_uniq.join(", ") + ".<br>"); 

    
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make use of `concat()`:

```js
    let Nr22_array_0 = ["apple","food","car"];
    let Nr22_array_1 = ["test","food","car", "miau"];
    let myArr = Nr22_array_0.concat(Nr22_array_1);
    
    console.log(myArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 spread operator to form a new array from the two arrays

```js
const arr1 = ['foo', 'boo']
const arr2 = ['bar', 'gar']

const join = [...arr1, ...arr2]
console.log(join)
```

Comment: oh damn i think i forgor something to say. it is just an example for 2 array's but if i have 500 or more with just the same name like Nr22_array_ and an different [N]?

Comment: are the arrays in an array?

Answer (score 0):

```
let concatenatedArray = [].concat(Nr22_array_0, Nr22_array_1);
```

In this case

> []

is creating a new array, and concat method is adding elements of Nr22_array_0 and Nr22_array_1 to that array.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Array#reduce to ensure that there are no doubles.

```js
const Nr22_array_0 = ["apple", "food", "car"];
const Nr22_array_1 = ["test", "food", "car", "miau"];
const res = Nr22_array_0
.concat(Nr22_array_1)
.reduce((acc,cur)=>{
  if(!acc.includes(cur)){ acc.push(cur) };
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

### Here is an alternative using Array#filter:

```js
const Nr22_array_0 = ["apple", "food", "car"];
const Nr22_array_1 = ["test", "food", "car", "miau"];
const res = [...Nr22_array_0, ...Nr22_array_1.filter(item=>!Nr22_array_0.includes(item))]

console.log(res);
```

### For N arrays:

```js
const Nr22_array_0 = ["apple", "food", "car"];
const Nr22_array_1 = ["test", "food", "car", "dog"];
const Nr22_array_2 = ["exam", "test", "car", "cat"];
const Nr22_array_3 = ["test", "apple", "machine", "world"];

function mergeNArrays() {
  return Object.values(arguments).reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc.push(...cur.filter(item => !acc.includes(item)))
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

const res = mergeNArrays(
  Nr22_array_0,
  Nr22_array_1,
  Nr22_array_2,
  Nr22_array_3
);

console.log(res);
```

**How does this work?**

```
const res = mergeNArrays(
      Nr22_array_0,
      Nr22_array_1,
      Nr22_array_2,
      Nr22_array_3
);
```

Pass all the arrays to be merged into the function `mergeNArrays`.

---

```
function mergeNArrays() {
      return Object.values(arguments).reduce((acc, cur) => {
        acc.push(...cur.filter(item => !acc.includes(item)))
        return acc;
      }, []);
}
```

Since the number of arrays is not fixed, doing something like:

```
function mergeNArrays(arr1, arr2, arr3){}
```

is not possible.

To solve this we can use [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) to get all the arrays passed as parameters. However, it's not an `array` but an `object` that looks something like this:

```
{
  '0': ["apple", "food", "car"],
  '1': ["test", "food", "car", "dog"]
}
```

To convert this to an array we need to use `Object.values(arguments);` which returns this:

```
[
    ["apple", "food", "car"],
    ["test", "food", "car", "dog"]
]
```

Which is now something we can use `reduce` on:

```
Object.values(arguments).reduce((acc, cur) => {
   acc.push(...cur.filter(item => !acc.includes(item)))
   return acc;
}, []);
```

`acc` corresponds initially to an empty `[]`. For every iteration of `reduce` we add all the elements in `cur` (ex: `["apple", "food", "car"]`) that don't already exist in `acc`.

For the first iteration, none of the elements exist in `acc` yet so `cur.filter(/** etc **/)` returns this:

```
["apple", "food", "car"]
```

However, we don't want to add it as an array to acc but as a list of elements. the reason for the spread operation `...`, which transforms the array to this:

```
acc.push("apple", "food", "car");
```

And this continues till we've gone through every array in `arguments` and added all the elements that don't yet exist in `acc`.

### For N array names (NOT RECOMMENDED):

```js
const Nr22_array_0 = ["apple", "food", "car"];
const Nr22_array_1 = ["test", "food", "car", "dog"];
const Nr22_array_2 = ["exam", "test", "car", "cat"];
const Nr22_array_3 = ["test", "apple", "machine", "world"];
const Nr22_array_names = [
  "Nr22_array_0",
  "Nr22_array_1",
  "Nr22_array_2",
  "Nr22_array_3",
]
function mergeNArrays(arrays) {
  return arrays.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc.push(...cur.filter(item => !acc.includes(item)))
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

const res = mergeNArrays(
  Nr22_array_names.map(eval)
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: the topic poster wants to include the doubles: `I dont know how to hande it to get an output like that: ["apple","food","car","test","food","car", "miau"]`

Comment: @messerbill I agree you could read his question like that but it would seem his english isn't good and if you look at "Version 3" it states "OUTPUT - NOK" with NOK as "not ok". I think he's actually trying to get rid of doubles. I might be wrong, but we'll see.

Comment: @messerbill thx for reduce i have an other codesegment, that i didnt write it in, because it would just make the code to long and didnt have anything to do with the problem. sry i forgot to say its for N Arrays wit the same name and just an other N.

Comment: @EduardTester hard to understand what you mean. Could you please try and clarify? Thanks.

Comment: @kemicofa puh. sure. think about it, that exist 500 or more arrays wit some content in it wit the names Nr22_array_N, where N is 1 - 500 or more. Now i want to push the contents of all arrays in just one, but over an loop function.

Comment: @EduardTester check last solution in my post

Comment: @EduardTester I'll add comments in my post so you can better understand. Cheers.

Comment: @kemicofa thx i implement it in my code, but i have an other question. how can i implement all Nr22_array_N's in that const res function without typing all 500 or N times in it? i tried it with <code>Nr22_array_names.join(", </br>") + "";</code> but it still doenst work =/ the rest of your code i understand it a bit, but your coding style is a little bit advanced. i understand that you call a function which returns an other function in it which has again an function in it :D not necessary to explain, that filter, reduce and co are also functions, but i think i understood the most of your code

Comment: @EduardTester How and where are those arrays defined? Where do they exist? Did you manually define all 500 of them?

Comment: @kemicofa there are accross the same file and also in other files, which i want to implement it in that file. and not. the most of them would be defined by me ofc. but its just for me to understand how i can work with arrays in javascript. in the future i will play also with one object arrays which contain all the data in it and so on, but at the first time i need that to know. step by step :)

Comment: @EduardTester does `Nr22_array_names` contain all the names of the existing arrays?

Comment: @kemicofa the thinking about that is, that Nr22_array_names would contain all the exist names of arrays. so yes

Comment: @EduardTester why would you decide to store the "names" of the arrays instead of the actual arrays? You could technically do `mergeNArrays(...Nr22_array_names.map(eval))` and it should work but that may eventually cause security issues.

Comment: @EduardTester if you insiste on using array names then check last solution. Cheers. Dont' forget to upvote and mark as the right answer.